# How can i open wind gazebo 7

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-7

How can i open wind mode on gazebo 7 ? Without wind, my simulated fixed-wing aircraft does not glide.

I found an sdf file like this and tried to add the wind plugin to my sdf file but it didn't work.

https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/wind.sdf

Or if there is a fixed wing world with SITL protocol, I would be very happy if you can throw it

Answer (score 0):

The Gazebo Wind Plugin is not what will allow gliding. It will allow you to provide a constant wind field in the world.

The plugin that you want to enable gliding is the LiftDrag Plugin

You can see it in this example world

https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/lift_drag.sdf

However for full examples I would recommend looking at the PX4 project where they have most types of flying vehicles modeled, from various multicopters through fixed wing.

https://docs.px4.io/v1.12/en/simulation/gazebo.html

Comment: this does not answer the misguided question

Comment: As far as I can tell this does answer the stated need to make an aircraft glide. Looking at the Wind plugin is adding the second layer of complexity on top of the LiftDrag Plugin. And the PX4 Gazebo documentation that I pointed is the best reference that I know of of fixed-wing SITL integrations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have completed the installation of SITL for Mavlink commands. I can work with certain commands in the Gazebo simulation environment. Can you post a source or help me to install the liftdrag plugin in the SDF file for the world I will run? I am trying but it is not working.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted.

Comment: If this is the answer that you wanted, please accept it with the checkmark next to the voting flags so that the system shows it as such and others know that you don't need more help.

Comment: It sounds like you also have a followup question about how to integrate the plugin into your sdf file. Please ask that as it's own standalone question describing your new challenge and what' you've tried having learned this information, such that you can get help with that too.